# How to instantiante object & call setter on same line?

Tags: java

If I have an `Employee` class with a default constructor:

```
private String firstName;
public Employee(){}
```

and a setter:

```
public void setFirstName(String firstName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
```

Why does this attempt fail to instantiate and call the setter in the same line?

```
Employee employee = new Employee().setFirstName("John");
```

Answer (score 30):

You can also use this syntax:

```
Employee employee = new Employee() {{
    setFirstName("John");
}};
```

Though keep in mind that it's going to create an anonymous inner class and probably isn't what you want.

Comment: @whiskeysierra i mentioned it because lots of folks don't know about this syntax, and while it's easy to abuse, it also comes in handy every so often. ;)

Answer (score 10):

Because `setFirstName` doesn't return anything. If you want to chain methods then `setFirstName` would have to return `Employee`.

Another approach is to have a constructor that takes `firstName` as an argument.

Answer (score 4):

```
(employee = new Employee()).setFirstName("John");
```

performs instantiation and calling the setter, as you requested in the headline, but does not declare the variable as suggested in your code example.

```
(Employee employee = new Employee()).setFirstName("John");
```

will probably not work, I assume. But you can try.

Of course, you can always stuff multiple statements in one line.

```
Employee employee; (employee = new Employee()).setFirstName("John");
```

or

```
Employee employee = new Employee(); employee.setFirstName("John");
```

If I were you, I would settle for a parameterized constructor, though.

Answer (score 3):

The method `serFirstName` is of return type `void` (nothing). Try:

```
public Employee setFirstName(String fname) {
  this.firstName = fname;
  return this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this:

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setFirstName("John");
```

Comment: The question was how to instantiate on the same line

Comment: @Steve yes but doing it on one line with a setter is poor style. The above is more idiomatic.

Comment: Just use the Builder pattern and make the setter return the whole object at the end. Problem solved. Elegantly.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is a bit overkill, you could try using the [*builder pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

```
public class Employee{
    private String firstName;

    public static class Builder{
        private String firstName;

        public Builder firstName(String firstName){
            this.firstName = firstName;
            return this;
        }

        public Employee build(){
            return new Employee(this);
        }
    }

    private Employee(Builder builder){
        firstName = builder.firstName;
    }
}
```

Then you can do the following

```
Employee e = new Employee.Builder().firstName("John").build();
```

Comment: Why go though the trouble when you can just return the `this` at the end ov the setter?
 
The you would get a valid `Employee e = new Employee().setFirstName("John");`

Comment: If you chose to go with the Builder pattern, I recommend using Lombok. It helps you get rid of all the above boilerplate.
Take a look at this simple example: https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-builder

Answer (score 1):

Because the you want to set `employee` to the value of `.setFirstName("John");` which does not return anything because it is a `void`

So you could either change your setter to:

```
public Employee setFirstName(String fname) {
  this.firstName = fname;
  return this;
}
```

OR Create a second constructor for `Employee`

```
public Employee(String fname){this.firstName = fname;}
```

Which would set `firstname` on init.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your code to work, you would have to return the `Employee` (meaning "this") in the setter method `setFirstName`.

If you don't own the Employee class (I know this is just a simple example - but for the sake of argument) and cannot modify it, one way to solve that is using functional programming. You could declare yourself a function like this:

```
static final Function<String, Employee> EMPLOYEE = firstName -> {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setFirstName(firstName);
        return employee;
};
```

And then you can create your employee in one line like this:

```
Employee jake = EMPLOYEE.apply("Jake");
```

Maybe not exactly what you want, but still useful.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer builder pattern. However, to answer your question about one-liner, my response is:

From Java 8 onwards, you can utilize the fact that standard JavaBeans setters are compatible with `BiConsumer` as a method reference. I assume you want to chain multiple setters hence you can add following method to `Employee` class:

```java
    <T> Employee applySetter(BiConsumer<Employee,T> setter, T value) {
        setter.accept(this, value);
        return this;
    }
```

and (assuming there is another field `int age` with appropriate setter) then call:

```
    Employee employee = new Employee()
            .applySetter(Employee::setFirstName, "Joe")
            .applySetter(Employee::setAge, 42);
```

Pros:

- one liner
- type-safe generics

Cons:

- poorly readable, nonidiomatic solution
- hardly to be universal for multiple entities

  - if `Employee` doesn't have superclass you must copypaste the `applySetter` method
  - if `Employee extends SomeRootEntity`, you need [self types](https://www.sitepoint.com/self-types-with-javas-generics/) to push `applySetter` up and declare it as `<SELF,T> Employee applySetter(BiConsumer<SELF,T> setter, T value)`)